# UIPageViewController + UIWebView + Flicker

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm currently developing a magazine style iPad app. Similar to that of Wired and other publications on the app store.

I have used a UIPageViewController for navigation. Curls to and from each page like iBooks.
The app is landscape with no spine. Each page takes up the whole screen.

The data for this app is being delivered by HTML in blocks. One page will usually have 4-6 blocks depending on the layout of the page.
So each page view controller has a number of UIWebView controls.

At any given time only three pages are present in memory. The current page, the page to the left, and the page to the right. All other pages are released and recreated when needed.

This all works great. But I have one issue.

When flipping from pages quickly, the UIWebView does not have time to load and as a consequence an unnatural flicker is displayed to the user.

I also have a control where you can skip to any desired page you want. Similar function to the iBooks page scroller.
So when on page 2, and selecting page 9 using this control, this UIWebView loading flicker also occurs.

Can anyone offer me any ideas that might help me with this problem.
Or is this just something you have to deal with when using UIWebView?

I could probably provide some code if you need it, but I'm more interested in the theory and the best practices of a task like this.

Comment: consider fading content in and out?

Comment: Yeah thanks, that helps. Looks much better.